# Excel 2016: repeat rows fill series for 4 repeat numbers

Tags: excel

Using Excel 2016

I am trying to repeat numbers twice for example I start with

```
1281
1281
1282
1282
1283
1283
...
```

What I did is I made the first 4 rows

```
1281
1281
1282
1282
```

and then I started the grab them down but I get between them 1 number repeated
like so..

```
1281
1281
1282
1282
1283
1283
1283
1284
1284
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You could do it with a formula. Put the first value in `A2` and the following formula in `A3`: `=IF(A1=A2,A2+1,A2)`, then populate down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel is trying to interpolate a pattern, but doing it badly. It expects to see an increase every row and isn't "smart" enough to detect a "repeat once, then increment" pattern.

If you expanded the decimal places displayed on your data, you would see that Excel is increasing every row by a fraction, but rounding:

```
1281.0
1281.0
1282.0
1282.0
1282.5
1282.9
1283.3
1283.7
1284.1
1284.5
1284.9
```

This produces the result you saw.

You would be better off using the `MOD()` function. Example:

```
    A
1   1281
2   =A1 + MOD(ROW(), 2)
3   =A2 + MOD(ROW(), 2)
4   =A3 + MOD(ROW(), 2)
...
```

This gives the result you're after. If you don't need to keep the formula for future rows, you can always calculate it once, then copy and paste the values.